# MariaDB LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE via JDBC with InputStream

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-connector-j

We are moving from MySQL 8.0.34 to MariaDB. Using the database is a Tomcat 10.1 application in Java 17.0.1.

As the  MariaDB connector is supposed to work with both systems, first thing is to change the applications to use the MariaDB 3.3.2 connector. So far everything seemed smooth, but I got stuck on one problem.

I cannot get `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` using an InputStream to work as it did with the MySQL connector.

Original lines (for the MySQL connector) that work were:

```
        com.mysql.cj.jdbc.JdbcStatement st = (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.JdbcStatement) connection.unwrap(com.mysql.cj.jdbc.JdbcConnection.class).createStatement();
        st.setLocalInfileInputStream(csv);
[...]
        st.execute("load data local infile '' into table temp_mlp fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"';");
```

Equivalent lines do not work with the MariaDB 3.3.2 connector  :

```
        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
        org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement st = s.unwrap(org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.class);
        st.setLocalInfileInputStream(csv);
[...]
        st.execute("load data local infile '' into table temp_mlp fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"';");
```

is giving

```
    java.sql.SQLException: (conn=8913298) Could not send file :  (AdresÃ¡Å™ nebo soubor neexistuje)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:306)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.export.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:366)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.message.ClientMessage.readPacket(ClientMessage.java:200)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readPacket(StandardClient.java:913)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResults(StandardClient.java:852)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.readResponse(StandardClient.java:771)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.execute(StandardClient.java:695)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.executeInternal(Statement.java:1035)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:1165)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:493)
[...]
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (AdresÃ¡Å™ nebo soubor neexistuje)
```

(By the way, developers that make localized programming error messages deserve a smack. It means directory or file does not exist.)

Changing the SQL to `load data local infile 'dummy' into table temp_mlp fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"';"` makes no difference.

Aanother way of setting the InputStream that makes no difference:

```
        org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement st = (org.mariadb.jdbc.Statement) connection.unwrap(org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection.class).createStatement();
        st.setLocalInfileInputStream(csv);
```

The JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/beletrik2?allowLocalInfile
```

Setting the parameter to `true` or omitting it makes no difference.

The stack trace suggests that setting the InputStream has no effect and the connector is trying to load the given file. But setting it yields no error.  Is it the correct way to set the InputStream? Is it supposed to work when the underlying database is MySQL? Or might it be a bug?

Comment: mariadb is known to have sometimes issue, maybe see if there is an update for server and connector

Comment: I am not in control of the MySQL server, but this is clearly a connector issue. The connector is latest version (3.3.2). However  I might eventually try downgrading.

Comment: that are non ascii characters in the error message, maybe a change of the connection charcterset set to utf8 would already help

Comment: Thanks but no, this is Tomcat log. There were some problems with UTF-8 in MySQL many years ago, but not now and one of the things still in place from then indeed is explicit setting of UTF-8 for all connections.

Comment: could you share the removed part [...] ? because a difference between those 2 drivers is that for mariadb connector, setting LocalInfileInputStream will only work for the next executed command, while for mysql the value stay forever.

Comment: Oh my god, that's probably it! I set the value and then basically run through a SQL file. I had no idea. Is it documented at all?

Comment: >Oh my god, that's probably it! => not documented, but i've always think it was an error in mysql connector first, like setting passing a parameter setString(1, "myValue") that will last forever

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the reason. I agree that in MariaDB it is cleaner, however the difference in implementation should be mentioned at least on the page describing differences of both systems.